# Trouble with remote access

Tags: ssh

I have a Ubuntu server set up on a pi4. I want to be able to access that server remotely. So i set up an account on No-IP and I got a domain. Then I downloaded OpenSSH and put in my new details.

I also set up port forwarding on my router. Picture of my admin page:

[image: Screenshot]

When I try to login using ssh in my terminal using my local IP, its fine. However when I try with the domain it doesn't work. What might be the issue here?

I tried logging in not connected to my network and I got this error message:

```
    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
    @       WARNING: POSSIBLE DNS SPOOFING DETECTED!          @
    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
    The ECDSA host key for MYSITE.sytes.net has changed,
    and the key for the corresponding IP address MYIP
    is unknown. This could either mean that
    DNS SPOOFING is happening or the IP address for the host
    and its host key have changed at the same time.
    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
    @    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
    IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
    Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
    It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
    The fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is
    SHA256:copdg+O/MYKEY
    Please contact your system administrator.
    Add correct host key in /home/nick/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
    Offending ECDSA key in /home/nick/.ssh/known_hosts:3
      remove with:
      ssh-keygen -f "/home/nick/.ssh/known_hosts" -R "rpiserver.sytes.net"
    ECDSA host key for MYSITE.sytes.net has changed and you have requested strict checking.
```

Comment: I believe this is expected behaviour. The SSH server reports an IP address that is different from what the client expects.

Comment: Run "ssh-keygen -f "/home/nick/.ssh/known_hosts" -R "rpiserver.sytes.net" " command. Like it say.